# Increasing Memory Limit in R

Tags: r

The memory.limit and memory.size functions are retired in the current R. Are there any other ways to increase the allocated memory for R to run some rather big matrix operation (over 354 GB).

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is simply "Cannot allocate a vector of size 300 Gb" etc. Nothing else.

Comment: I also just checked with sessionInfo(), here is the output for LAPACK/BLAS: Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

Comment: 128 GB. A workstation. Normally it's fast and sufficient, but not this time.

Comment: Yes, virtual memory is set to unlimited.